# issue with azure blob connector in power automate

Tags: azure, powerapps, power-automate

I have a Power automate Flow which uses Azure blob connector to read excel file from the blob using the Get blob content action.
The problem is I need to process the excel data and save it in D365 f and O entity. for that I need the data in json format. I saw we can use cloudmersive connector to convert excel to json
I want to do it without using any 3rd party connector.?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file, and insert it into a table. After that, you can use compose actions or arrays to assign them to a JSON object.